# How to deploy docker app in aws using GitLab CI/CD

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Symfony app that runs with docker-compose and I want to implement the auto-deployment with GitLab CI/CD, to run the app in some aws instance. I don't know what would be the best approach to take, basically this are my ideas and their steps:

Approach 1: (building in GitLab)

- Build the docker images in the GitLab runners
- Push the images to some image registry
- ssh to the aws instance
- pull the new image
- run the new containers with docker-compose

Approach 2: (building in aws)

- ssh to aws
- pull the branch to deploy
- build the docker images
- run the new containers with docker-compose

I like the first approach but maybe there is another better way to do it. It would be amazing to have some `.gitlab-ci.yml` reference file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you build it in GitLab runners and push it to a registry, you can use it in more places that only on AWS.

Here is a reference file for the Docker-in-Docker build method(from [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html)):

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
build:
   image: docker:stable
   services:
     - docker:dind
   variables:
     DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
     DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
   stage: build
   script:
     - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.example.com
     - docker build -t registry.example.com/group/project/image:latest .
     - docker push registry.example.com/group/project/image:latest
```

Comment: this is OK for CI, but there is no CD here